# Mac: Disable Keyboard-Shortcut for symbol

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

On my mac, typing Option-Shift-R in any text field in any program inserts a "‰" character.  The problem is that I use `Option-Shift-R` as a special shortcut in another program (PyCharm), and whenever I use this key it both executes the action in pycharm and types the character, which is annoying.

Given that I've never once needed the "per-mille" symbol in my life, is there a way on mac to disable this shortcut?  There seems to be no option for it in the "Keyboard -> Shortcuts" menu.

Answer (score 2):

It is your keyboard layout that's producing "‰" when you press Option-Shift-R. (It's also what produces "A" when you press the A key, and everything else.)

You can try switching to a different built-in keyboard layout using System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources, but you probably won't find one which produces nothing when you press Option-Shift-R.

So, your best bet is probably to create a custom keyboard layout and use that. There's an app called [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) that can help create such custom keyboard layouts. I haven't check recently, but I'm fairly sure it can create a new one by copying one of the built-in layouts, which you then tweak just a bit so most things work just as you expect.